# How to test spring beans in a sub-module project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

My main project uses spring-boot and maven. I created another maven module that I want to use it as dependency to my main project. So my new module don't need to be a runnable spring-boot project. But I am still using some spring annotations also it has its own configuration properties.

Problem I'm having is with testing this module. I didn't add this module yet to the main project, I want to do that after I write all the tests and the code, since its more convenient.

So my questions is, is it possible to write test while I have no real Spring application context in my code? For example all fields below comes null, and not testable. Is it because of missing application context or something else?

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = CustomerConfiguration.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")
public class CustomerServiceTest {

@Autowired
CustomerService service;   (NULL)

@Autowired
CustomerConfiguration config;  (NULL)


@Test
public void getCustomerTest() {
    ..some tests
    service.getCustomer();
}
}
```

And Service class:

```
 @Service
 public class CustomerService {
 }
```

and my pom is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: naturally without application context there is nowhere to autowire from hence all nulls. You can add one module as a dependency for the other which should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following "main" class to your test sources:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class TestApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<TestApplication>(*args)
}
```